# converting forcelayout from d3 v3 to d3 v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

can anyone help me to convert the code mentioned in [d3.js - Force Layout and Node Positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36790490/d3-js-force-layout-and-node-positions) to d3 v5? Here is my portion, but I am getting error svg.append(...).attr(...).selectAll(...).data(...).enter is not a function" at drawGraph. Actually my target is to find the node positions after the end of force layout. Using these positions I am going to find the distance of each nodes.

```
 var graph = {
      "nodes": [{
      "name": "a",
      "group": 1
      }, {
      "name": "b",
      "group": 8
      }],
      "links": [{
      "source": 1,
      "target": 0,
      "value": 1
      }
   };
     var width = 600;var height = 600;
    function getPosition(force) {
     return force.nodes().map(function(node) {
        return {
        name: node.name,
        group: node.group,
        x: node.x,
        y: node.y
       }
     })
   }
   var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);       
   var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
                .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d,i) {
                    return i;
                }).distance(30))
                .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-120 ))
                .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2,height / 2))
                .on('end', function(){
                    var position = getPosition(simulation);
                    console.log(position)
                    });  
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height);
    var drawGraph = function(graph) {
       var link = svg.append('g')
                  .attr('class','links')
                  .selectAll("line")
                  .data(graph.link)
                  .enter()
                  .append("line");  
    var nodes = svg.append('g').attr("class", "nodes")
                   .selectAll("g")
                   .data(graph.nodes)
                   .enter()
                   .attr("r", 10)
                   .style("fill", function(d) {
                        return color(d.group);
                    })
                    .append("title")
                    .text(function(d) {
                            return d.name;
                    })
                   .call(simulation.drag);                              
    simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);
    simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);
       function ticked(){
            links.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
               .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
               .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
               .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
            nodes.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
               .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

       };
      drawGraph(graph);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 errors in you code first in `var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)` it should be `var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(graph.nodes)` and second in `.data(graph.link)` it should be `.data(graph.links)` that's why you are getting not a function error. As "**link**" is not in your data its **links**.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As per your instructions. I solved the error and got the node positions. But the code does not display any node-link output. Can you help me in this purpose?

Comment: Thank you again. I checked the code. Actually I did not mention the node type, size and link color. So, everything is ok now. Thank you Again.